# jquery selector on javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

Hey guys I'm having trouble implementing some jQuery code. I have a javascript function that stores the element that the function was called from (a td) and then selects it's parent node and changes the class of that parentnode (a tr). I would like to change it to jQuery so I can take ad vantage of the .addClass tool. Here is the code

```
   function draftHandler(teamID, element, from, name, pos)
{
     if(...something...) 
          element.parentNode.className = "drafted";
}
```

I have been trying something like...

```
element.closest('tr').addClass('drafted');
```

...without any luck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without seeing your markup and how you're calling this function, any answers you get are going to be "best guesses"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('td').parent('tr').addClass('drafted').
```

You can replace `$('td')` with the element.

The `parent('tr')` is only added security making sure you indeed add the class to the parent tr element. It's not needed IF the first parent of your `td` is in fact a `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(element).closest('tr').addClass('drafted');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  $(element).parent().addClass('drafted');
```